# How to pass, in parameter, a class and use its methods

Tags: java, class, methods, parameter-passing

As the title presumes, how do I this in Java? What im trying to do is something like this

first there is a class

```
public class MyFirstModel() {

    //standard constructor
    public MyFirstModel(){
            //some lines of codes
    }

    //A method
    public String getvalue() {

            //do something then
            return result;
    }
}
```

And the second Model(class)

```
public class MySecondModel() {

    //standard constructor
    public MySecondModel(){
            //some lines of codes
    }

    //A method
    public String getvalue() {

            //do something then
            return result;
    }
}
```

Having those two, sample, models i want to pass a class depending on the, action. Let's just say there are two buttons and the first button is for the model and the second is for the second model. The third class that is to be pass to:

```
 FinalClass fclass = new FinalClass(<class here>);  <-- how do i pass the class here
```

Here, how do I pass the class? on the FinalClass, what would be its constructor? and how do I acces the methods of the passed class?

I hope you guys get what I mean. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to pass the actual `class`(`MySecondModel.class`) or an instance of one or the other?

Comment: Do both of your modules share an interface? if they did, passing an instance would be much easier.

Comment: from what i can see either your problem can be solved either by generics or a simple interface?.  If you want to pass in the name of the class and let final class create objects maybe you are looking for reflection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to have both models implement an interface?

MyModel.java:

```
public interface MyModel {
    public String getValue();
}
```

MyFirstModel.java:

```
public class MyFirstModel implements MyModel {
    public String getValue() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

MySecondModel.java:

```
public class MySecondModel implements MyModel {
    public String getValue() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

CallingClass.java:

```
public class CallingClass {
    private MyModel model = null;
    public CallingClass(MyModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Then you can construct MyModel however you want and pass it in to CallingClass.

Comment: Wow I like this code. Let me try this for size. Thank you for the reply guys.

Comment: I have question. Is the MyModel is the only one that can be pass here? how do I pass either MySecondModel or MyFirstModel?

Comment: Sorry, `MyFirstModel` and `MySecondModel` should have been classes instead of interfaces (edited to fix).  You can construct `CallingClass` either way, as `new CallingClass(new MyFirstModel())` or `new CallingClass(new MySecondModel())`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this actually works. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Anonymous Object by using an interface:

```
public interface FinalClass {
   // Method definitions
}

public class MyFirstModel() implements FinalClass {
    //...
}

public class MySecondModel() implements FinalClass {
    //...
}
```

Use:

```
FinalClass fclass = new MyFirstModel();
// or
FinalClass fclass = new MySecondModel();
```